# Do most real world join conditions involve no more than 2 columns?

Tags: join, condition

In the database application I have worked on, all join conditions are binary, like

```
select * from A join B join C on A.id=B.id and B.orderno = C.orderno
```

Each condition, separated by "and", is a binary condition, that involves columns from 2 tables.

I know these conditions could involve variables from more than 2 tables, such as:

```
select * from A join B join C on A.x+B.x+C.x<10 and A.y+B.y+C.y<100
```

in the "real world" applications, are tertiary and more complex join conditions common?

Comment: I feel that `JOIN` criteria are best defined using _only_ tuple equality operators with all other predicates in the `WHERE` clause, this is because that's how foreign-key constraints are implemented (i.e. as an fk index contains). The execution-plan should still be the same, but it means you can instantly tell at-a-glance if a `JOIN ON` criteria is "correct" or not by simply comparing it to the relevant FK constraint definition.

Comment: ON clause may contain any expression whose value can be treated as boolean. For example, the correlated subquery in ON clause of the next query is completely legal: `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM t3 WHERE t3.f3 BETWEEN t1.f1 AND t2.f2)`. *are tertiary and more complex join conditions common?* No, this is rare exotic.